# Is there any way to compute dtype('<m8[ns]')?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have done an operation subtracting two datetime columns to find out the duration between those two dates. I am very new to python also new to the site, I want to know how to work on dtype('<m8[ns]'), because the resultant output comes out as the following:

```
    ar = pd.to_datetime(['12/31/2015 23:55','1/1/2016 2:47'])
    print(ar[1]-ar[0])
```

this would give the OUT as :

```
0 days 02:52:00
```

How do I use this data type to perform operations, such as how do i find out if this data is less than 1 day or one hour?

your help is much appreciated.

Comment: `print(ar[1]-ar[0] < pd.Timedelta('1D'))`

Comment: thanks, how does it work for hours and minutes? Is there any article over the internet that can help me get through this?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html

Comment: Please note: Stackoverflow is not a tutorial website. You can find plenty of those for Python/pandas/timedelta using the search engine of your choice. If you have a specific problem, boil it down to a [mre] and ask it here.